Does $U'>0$ and $U''<0$ imply $U'''\geq 0$?
Say I have a continuous function $U:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ at least three times differentiable on an interval $I\ \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Assume it is strictly increasing and strictly concave on this interval (i.e., $U'>0$ and $U''<0$ on $I$).
Does that imply that $U'''\geq0$? If not, how to prove it? Are there counter-examples?
Many thanks in advance for your help!

No, not necessarily. Take $f:(0,\pi/2)\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=\sin(x)$.
Then, $f'(x)=\cos(x)>0$ and $f''(x)=-\sin(x)<0$ on $(0,\pi/2)$ but $f'''(x)=-\cos(x)<0$ on $(0,\pi/2)$.
